# From where value of intent is coming on which I am calling getAction() function? (This is overridden method of BroadcastReceiver class)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have created a broadcast receiver class Which is working fine. I am confused about from where the value of intent comes in onReceive method.

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       String action = intent.getAction();

       if(wifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))
       {
           int state=intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);

           if(state==WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
               Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi is ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else 
           {
               Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi is OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
}
```

Main Activity code where I have made an Intent Filter, where I have added an action.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_device);

        wifiP2pManager =  (WifiP2pManager) 

getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel = wifiP2pManager.initialize(this,getMainLooper(),null);

        broadcastReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(wifiP2pManager, channel, this);

      intentFilter =  new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your BroadcastReceiver works, then you must have initialized `wifiP2pManager` and called a function on the object. When tbe state changes an intent is being broadcasted. With the receiver you subscribe to those intents.

You can read in more detail about the WifiP2pManager in the Android documentation [Wi-Fi Direct (peer-to-peer or P2P) overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p)

Comment: I have also added code where I initialized wifiP2pManager. What do you mean by state changes? Are you saying change in state of system i.e if wifi turns on or off? And this change will be notified through this intent. Please explain a little more. Thank you

Comment: If the `wifiP2pManager ` discovers, connects, etc. then the state is changed and the manager broadcasts intents. So if you received an intent, it's coming from the `wifiP2pManager `